# S2S: Trigger not firing on insert of new record?

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

When S2S inserts a new record (custom object) in the target org, the relevant trigger doesn't appear to fire. The record is successfully inserted, there are no error emails received by the connection owner. It does fire when inserting a record directly in the target org.

Any ideas?

```
trigger MyCustomObjectTrigger on My_Custom_Object__c (after insert) {

     System.debug('Whoop!');

}
```

Comment: Is there anything special about that trigger?

Comment: Nothing, just a System.debug('Whoop!');

Comment: Definitely seems weird! You couldn't boil the code down any more and this article doesn't mention S2S: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm

Comment: Yep, particularly considering I'm trying to implement a best practice: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practices_for_Salesforce_to_Salesforce ref "Reestablishing lookup relationships"

Comment: Something more meaningful might be `System.debug('Size Trigger New = ' + Trigger.New.size());` or something along those lines. What you have now doesn't tell you if any new records were inserted. Knowing if Trigger.New was empty or not would tell you whether something had been inserted. In fact a boolean results test for being empty would be sufficient for your debug statement.

Comment: @crmprogdev I would improve my debug statement, however I'm not seeing any logging, so either the Trigger isn't invoked or the Log is not generated, something that seems to be a bit of a problem with S2S in general.

Answer (score 2):

OK, the trigger is firing, it's just that I don't see a log entry on any of the monitored users, including the S2S Connection Owner user. Is there any way to monitor the logs generated by S2S actions?

BTW, I figured out it was firing by adding an: 
       `insert new Contact(lastname='test trigger fired')`

The Contact was created by "Connection User" and it's not possible to monitor this user in the Debug Logs. Great.

Comment: did you try this? http://screenfields.nl/blog/2012/08/09/debugging-salesforce-2-salesforce/

Comment: having done a bunch of work on S2S recently - you might want to look at my blog post for other tips/pitfalls: http://cropredysfdc.com/2014/11/17/s2s-salesforce-to-salesforce-adventures/

Comment: @PhilB - you should post your link as the answer

Comment: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000lg6kQAA

Comment: @PhilB the link is dead, do you still know what it said?